# Linear Programming Cutting Problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-programming

I'm doing some self studying and I have come across a problem I don't quite understand. The problem only gives me the single constraint:
[image]

The first question asks me to show that the given constraint implies the following cuts:
[image]

The second questions requires me to come up with a general rule for making cuts like the second cut from the given constraint:
[image]

The last question asks me how would I use this constraint to derive such cuts and wants me to convert it to the form in the second question:
[image]

I can see the constraint requiring less than four or five "1" values at minimum but I'm not quite sure how I would go about showing it. I haven't been able to find a question of similar nature anywhere else so I turn to people here hoping they might understand what I don't.

Comment: Is there any constraint on $y_5$?

Comment: Only constraint is that it is 0-1 ILP. All yi values are either 0 or 1 integers.

Comment: So there is no typo, and the first equation actually is intended to be equivalent to
$(9)y_1 + (21)y_2 + (13)y_3 + (15)y_4 + (18)y_6 \leq 52$?

Comment: What does "ILP" refer to?  Also, assuming no typo, does this mean that it needs to be proven that since $1$ is an
upper bound for $y_5$, that it needs to be proven that
$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_6 \leq 4$ and $y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_6 \leq 3$?  Further,
if $1$ is also an upper bound for $y_1$, does this mean that the second inequality
implies the first?

Comment: There is a typo, thank you for catching it, y6 should be y5.ILP refers to Integer Linear Programming. After solving the LP relaxation using simplex method, if the solution is non-integer then new cuts are needed to be added to the tableau, which will produce primal infeasibility. My guess is that the question requires us to show this infeasibility but I am unsure.

Comment: Please edit your query to resolve typos.  Also, please remove the math graphics from your query, instead expressing the math with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I edited the type out of the constraint, it was in y2. I'll look into Mathjax.

Comment: Is $(9y_1 + 10y_2 + 11y_3 + 11y_4 + 13y_5 + 16y_6)$ automatically $\geq 9(y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_6)$?  If it is not the case that $(y_1 + \cdots + y_6) < 5$ does this imply that $(y_1 + \cdots y_6) \geq 6$.  If so, what does this say about $9(y_1 + \cdots + y_6)$?

Comment: I don't see why (9y1 + 10y2 + 11y3 + 11y4 + 13y5 + 16y6) wouldn't automatically be bigger than or equal to 9(y1 + y2 + ⋯ + y6) in a 0-1 integer problem. If the constraint was not the case then it would make sense for it to be >=6  but I don't quite see how it would say anything about 9(y1 + y2 + ⋯ + y6).

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 2):

These cuts are called *cover inequalities* or *no-good cuts*.  If your original constraint is $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i y_i \le a_0,$$
any subset $C \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $$\sum_{i\in C} a_i > a_0$$ yields a cover inequality
$$\sum_{i\in C} y_i \le |C|-1.$$
You can derive this via conjunctive normal form as follows:
$$
\lnot \bigwedge_{i\in C} y_i \\
\bigvee_{i\in C} \lnot y_i \\
\sum_{i\in C} (1 - y_i) \ge 1 \\
\sum_{i\in C} y_i \le |C|-1
$$
Your first cut arises from $C=\{1,\dots,6\}$ with $\sum_{i\in C} a_i = 70 > 52$,
and your second cut arises from $C=\{2,\dots,6\}$ with $\sum_{i\in C} a_i = 61 > 52$.

Comment: I think I understand the constraint of the form, I shall look into cover inequalities more thoroughly. Lastly could you expound on how I would convert the constraint in the last question to the one you derived in this answer?

Comment: I don't understand the last question.  Can you please provide a link to the source of the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what is being asked.  Please edit the question to match the exact wording.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments exchanged with OP.

If it is not the case that $(y_1 + \cdots + y_6) < 5$

then $(y_1 + \cdots + y_6) \geq 6.$

This implies that $9 \times (y_1 + \cdots + y_6) \geq 54.$

However, it is given that

$9 \times (y_1 + \cdots + y_6) \leq 
(9)y_1 + (10)y_2 + (11)y_3 + (11)y_4 + (13)y_5 + 16(y_6) = 52 < 54.$

Thus, the original constraint implies that
$9 \times (y_1 + \cdots + y_6) \leq 52.$

Therefore, since the assumption that 
it is not the case that $(y_1 + \cdots + y_6) < 5$ 
led to the conclusion that 
$9 \times (y_1 + \cdots + y_6) \geq 54$,

the assumption that it is not the case that $(y_1 + \cdots + y_6) < 5$
has caused a contradiction.

Therefore, the assumption must be false.

---

The 2nd part is reasoned in the following way.

If $y_2 + \cdots + y_6 \geq 5$, then

$y_2 + \cdots + y_6 = 5 \implies$

$10(y_2 + \cdots + y_6) = 50$.

From the original constraint, this implies that $y_1 = 0.$

Further, from the original constraint, since each variable must be in $\{0,1\}$, it is immediate that $y_5 = 0 = y_6$ (else the original constraint would have to be violated, since the sum would have to be at least $53$).

However, with $0 = y_1, y_5, y_6$, you can't have
$y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 5$, since the max value of each variable is $1$.

Thus, the assumption that $y_2 + \cdots + y_6 = 5$ has led to a contradiction.

**Addendum**
Responding to the question/comment of Songaro.

Assume that the following constraints are satisfied:

$$9y_1 + 10y_2 + 11y_3 + 11y_4 + 13y_5 + 16y_6 
\leq 52.\tag1$$

$$ y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 5. \tag2 $$

$$ y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_6 ~~\text{are each in}~~
\{0,1\}. \tag3$$

From (2) above, you know that
$$ 10y_2 + 10y_3 + 10y_4 + 10y_5 + 10y_6 = 50. \tag4$$

Subtracting (4) from (1) gives
$$9y_1 + y_3 + y_4 + 3y_5 + 6y_6 \leq 2.\tag5$$

Jointly considering (3) and (5) indicates that 
If any of $y_1, y_5,$ or $y_6$ are non-zero, (5) above will have to be **violated**.

Alternatively, assuming that $y_1, y_5, y_6$ are all zero indicates that (2) and (3) above can not jointly be satisfied.

Thus, (2) above has caused a contradiction.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind this but this only applies to the first constraint as the second constraint gives us 50 which does not cause a contradiction as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Songaro Answer edited for Part 2.  Unclear if I have made a mistake on the meaning of the constraints on the variables.  If so, please advise.

Comment: I do not understand why y5=0=y6, could you clarify that statement?

Comment: @Songaro see the Addendum that I just added to my answer.